# Eigen error when initializing dynamic matrix

Tags: c++, eigen

I am trying to populate an Eigen matrix (dyinamic rows, 2 columns, of doubles) from a vector containing some simple structure of cartesian points, however, I am getting an error when using operator `<<`.

Minimum failing example (using MSVC 2017):

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <vector>

struct point {
    double x, y;
};

int main() {

    std::vector<point> points = {
        point{0.0, 0.0},
        point{0.5, 0.0},
        point{0.0, 1.0},
        point{0.5, 1.0},
    };

    typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 2> CoordMatrix;
    CoordMatrix X;

    for (auto& p : points)
        X << p.x, p.y;

    return 0;
}
```

When running this, I get an error in the line `X << point.x, point.y;` saying: "No operator `<<` matches these operands" (this also throws when trying to pass `X << 0.0, 0.0;` while in debug mode).

Comment: `X << {p.x, p.y};` ?

Comment: That gives a bunch of syntax errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you are trying to initialize the `X` matrix with values in each row containing coordinates of one of the points from the earlier vector. You can't do it that way, see [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html):

> Eigen offers a comma initializer syntax which allows the user to easily set all the coefficients of a matrix, vector or array. Simply list the coefficients, starting at the top-left corner and moving from left to right and from the top to the bottom. The size of the object needs to be specified beforehand. If you list too few or too many coefficients, Eigen will complain.

The above clearly states that you the right hand side needs to match dimensions to the left hand side. In your case you would probably need to copy the vector element by element. Something like:

```
CoordMatrix X(points.size(), 2); // reserving rigth storage for the matrix
for (auto i = 0u; i < points.size(); ++i) {
  X(i, 0) = points[i].x;
  X(i, 1) = points[i].y;
}
```

Comment: Ah, true... didn't see that the first time I read the documentation. I guess I should read more carefully, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to use the `<<` initialization, you can do that one row at a time (and as @paler123 already said, you need to allocate `X` before storing values into it):

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 2> CoordMatrix;
CoordMatrix X(points.size(), 2); // allocate space for matrix
Eigen::Index r=0; // or use `r` as counter in the loop
for (auto& p : points)
    X.row(r++) << p.x, p.y; // fill matrix one row per iteration
```

You can also map the memory of `points` to an `Eigen::Map` directly -- in that case you must make sure that the storage order agrees and that `points` does not get modified if you still use `X`, but `X` will require no extra memory (except for a pointer and an `Index`).

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 2, Eigen::RowMajor> CoordMatrix;
auto X = CoordMatrix::Map(&points[0].x, points.size(), 2); // no copy happens
// X gets invalid if `points` are destructed or re-allocated.
```